# Swift WebKit WebView Open ICS Calendar Event

Tags: swift, webview, wkwebview

Loading this link in a WKWebView results in a blank page: `https://www.cvs.com/addToCalendar?apptDate=04/21/2021&apptTime=04:15`

The same URL opens the calendar invite popup when opened in the Safari app.

This is the error that's returned:

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "data:text/calendar;charset=utf8,BEGIN:VCALENDAR%0AVERSION:2.0%0ABEGIN:VEVENT%0ADTSTART:20210421T081500Z%0ADTEND:20210421
> ... CALENDAR" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme
> data"

What I've tried:

-Adding `calendar`, `calshow`, `x-apple-reminder`, and `cal` to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. I

What needs to be done to let a WebView open this link?

Comment: A web view is by no means a full implementation of Safari, and this pop up in Safari is clearly outside the web view. You could either open the URL in Safari or open it in a SFSafariViewController.

Comment: This is a terrible response. Safari is built on WebKit. If they can do it then it is achievable here. @e

Comment: Not being the response you wanted doesn’t make it a “terrible response”. I don’t know how you expect a subview to display a view controller on top of your app, but good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In our case, to achieve this we have added a deeplink handler to redirect the url to specific action.
such as

URL opened in webview:

`https://www.myapp.com/redirectabc?data=xxxx&contentType=xxxx&filename=xxx`

and in webview class

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
     if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
         if url.absoluteString.contains("redirectabc")  {
             UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
             decisionHandler(.cancel)
             return
         }
     }
}
```

In server side:

```
return response((string) $data, 200, [
    'Content-Type' => $contentType,
    'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"",
]);
```

This will make the webview to trigger app to open the url by safari and go to calendar app.

It is a lil bit messy but still able to save a ICS event.

Comment: Hm. Interesting but there needs to be a work around to catch ICS events from any url. This answer only works for one specific site. How would you make this catch all events? @jack

Comment: If the ICS url is connect with a ICS file, calling `UIApplication.shared.open(ICS_URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)` will do the job. Our use case is having a raw ICS data generated on webview.

Answer (score -1):

You can use UIDocumentInteractionController to handle Calendar links & downloads. Here's some example code:

```
if downloadedFile.mimeType == MIMEType.Calendar {
            let dc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: downloadedFile.path)
            dc.delegate = self
            dc.presentPreview(animated: true)
            return
}
```